# What is the difference between the words "over" and "here"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, difference, australian-english

I've noticed that sometimes English speakers use *over* similar to *here*, e.g. once me and my friend saw a girl walking he said *call her over* -- here it seems like he meant *call her here.* In another instance, my friend said *bring it over(sheet)*, here he meant bring the sheet here, because when I couldn't understand he said *bring it over here*. On another occasion I was told *come over* and when I didn't respond he said *move to my side*.

So, to me both *over* and *here* seem to have same meaning. What is the difference between *over* and *here*?

Comment: In *Come over here* and *Go over there*, the word ***over*** effectively means ***away from*** (wherever the speaker and/or addressee are currently), so it's not really "necessary" in either of my two examples. But just as the single word ***here / there*** on its own can imply ***over** here / there*, so we often just use ***over*** to mean *over **here / there***.

Comment: Thus you might phone a friend and say *I'm bored. Can **I** come over?* (meaning *over to **your** place, away from "here" where **I** am now).* But equally, you might say *I'm bored. Can **you** come over?* (meaning *over to **my** place, away from "there" where **you** are now).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers That looks like a very good answer to me (might be worth pointing out  that *over* and *here* are both prepositions).

Comment: No one I know says "Call her here" for: Tell her to come here. And again, we are off topic re the OP's question, where "Call her here"is simply wrong. The question was: what is the difference between over and here, which I think I answered.

Comment: *Call her here* makes it sound like *her* is a dog, small child, or someone/something expected to obey.

Answer (score 1):

*Over* is a weird word, it's heavily overloaded with a lot of different meanings, and there's no easy way to know other than context.

- It can mean on top of and covering.  *The plates are over the placemats.*
- It can mean done or completed.  *The event is over*.
- It can mean you have to climb something to get to something else.  *The house is over the hill.*
- It can mean "greater than".  *Over 2 hours I waited.*
- It can mean "get out of the way", often implying lateral movement.  *I asked him to move over*.
- It can mean "come from out of the way or a far distance".  *Come over to my house*.
- Phrasal verbs/well-known phrases: *to go over* means "to examine in detail", *hung over* - what you are after drinking a lot the next day, *take over* - to assume ownership of, authority of, or to conquer, etc.

*Here* is a lot simpler, it just means "where I am."

You can even say *come over here, please.* to mean "come (from a far distance or out of my way) to where I am, please."

*Come over* is a very common phrase, as is *move over*, you can basically memorize these as equivalent to *come here* and *move away*.

And it is entirely possible but somewhat rare for *move over* to mean "move (from a far distance or out of my way) to where I am, please", but this will almost always be said as *move over here* or the person will be motioning toward you if they mean for you to move near them.